# Is there any way to use break statement in while loop of jmeter [Jmeter Performance Testing]

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to performance testing using **jmeter**. I wrote a script in which I was using a while controller but I want to break that loop if some unexpected condition happens. So is there a way to use a break statement in a while loop controller?

Comment: where is your script "as you said **i wrote a script**"

Comment: script contained some confidential API so thats why not allowed to put here

Answer (score 4):

Samplers inside the While controllers are getting executed until the condition is true.

We can set the condition in the while controllers. You can just use a variable containing a boolean value (TRUE/FALSE) or You can use javascript expression returning a boolean value.

- ${VAR} - where VAR is set to false by some other test element
- ${__javaScript(${C}==10)}
- ${__javaScript("${VAR2}"=="abcd")}
- ${_P(property)} - where property is set to "false" somewhere else

[Check here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)  for more details.

Create an user defined variable 'CONDITION' & let the value be TRUE.
Now, whenever the unexpected condition happens, set the value to FALSE using beanshell post processor.  That should take care of it.

[image]

---

I have also come up with my own controller to exit from the loop whenever the assertion failures happens. Please check for more details.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-until-controller/